# How do i get body from the below NSObject object in Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nsstring, nsobject

So i'm trying to do push notifications and i've been able to get the "aps" and "alert" objects out of this,but i'm having issues extracting "body" and "title" out of this, any help would be deeply appreciated

```
    {{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = asdads;
            title = aaas;
        };
    };
    "mobile_center" =     {
    };
}}
```

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: var valu = userInfo1.ValueForKey(new NSString("title"));

Comment: @tx2 which is not working,throws null

Comment: Can you try var valu = userInfo1.ValueForKey(new NSString("aps")); just to see what the result is?

Comment: did userInfo1.ValueForKey(new NSString("alert").ValueForKey(new NSString("body"))); and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userInfo1.ValueForKey(new NSString("alert").ValueForKey(new NSString("body")));
```

Did the Trick